# How to generate database table use by Audit.EntityFramework.Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, audit.net

I have follow the instruction in below url of how to setup the Audit.net for aspnetcore and sql server as the datasource.

https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/tree/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework

however i am receiving an error as below.

Invalid object name 'dbo.Event'

Answer (score 1):

As per their documentation, you need to create the table called Events. It won't create the table automatically. If you want to create try EF Migration on code.